# SQL Select query to pull multiple values from the same row as individual rows

Tags: sql, db2

I have a datatable that stores location values as such:
CTY_CD, STATE_CD, COUNTRY_CD and I want to select from this table given a city code and select all three location codes as individual rows with another column showing what loc type it is, so the results of the query would look like:

```
Given city code DEN:

Type         |    Code
CTY_CD            DEN
STATE_CD          CO
COUNTRY_CD        US
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Post the input records and result to make it more clear.

Comment: unpivot https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
 select 'CTY_CD' AS Type,  CTY_CD AS Code FROM tableName WHERE CTY_CD = 'DEN'
 UNION
 select 'STATE_CD' AS Type, STATE_CD AS Code FROM tableName WHERE CTY_CD = 'DEN'
 UNION
 select 'COUNTRY_CD' AS Type, COUNTRY_CD AS Code FROM tableName WHERE CTY_CD = 'DEN'
```